# Error : INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got this error on the line

```
db.Comments.Add(comment);
db.SaveChanges();
```

and I can't fix it... What's the issue? I've read many question on that issue, but can't find from where the issue come in my code.

I'm using asp.net mvc4, c# and Entity Framework.

My comment model has a `PostId` property.

> *The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Comments_dbo.Posts_PostId". The conflict occurred in
>   database Myproject, table "dbo.Posts", column 'PostId'.
>
>   The statement has been terminated.*

**EDIT :**

*I've noticed that, my comment.PostId is equal to 0 when SaveChanges() is called*

*I've noticed that, if I had `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PostId)` in my CreateComment view, then i've got no error anymore, but nothing happens when I click to add the comment*

`PostController`:

```
        public ActionResult ListPost()
        {
            var post = db.Posts.ToList();
            return PartialView("ListPost", post);
        }


        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(); 
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection values)
        {
            var post = new Post();
            TryUpdateModel(post);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var context = new UsersContext();
                var username = User.Identity.Name;
                var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
                var userid = user.UserId;                

                post.UserId = userid;
                post.Date = DateTime.Now;

                db.Posts.Add(post);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Create", "Post"); 
            }
            return View(post);
        }


    public ActionResult CreateComment()
    {
        ViewBag.PostId = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostId", "Content");
        return View("CreateComment");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateComment(FormCollection values)
    {
        var comment = new Comment();
        TryUpdateModel(comment);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var context = new UsersContext();
            var username = User.Identity.Name;
            var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            var userid = user.UserId;

            comment.UserId = userid;
            comment.Date = DateTime.Now;

            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Post");
        }
        ViewBag.PostId = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostId", "Content", comment.PostId);
        return View(comment);
    }
```

Create view (call the ListPost partial View) :

```
@model Myproject.Models.Post

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Post", FormMethod.Post))
{  
        <legend>Add Post</legend>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
            <input type="file" name="Photo" id="Photo"/>
        </div>   

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Post" />
        </p> 
}

@{Html.RenderAction("ListPost", "Post");}
```

ListPost partial view (call the CreateComment view) :

```
    @model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Post>

    @foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users.UserName)</span>    
            </td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
       <td> @Html.ActionLink("Add Comment", "CreateComment", new {id=item.PostId})</td>      
    </tr>
 }
```

**EDIT 2**

Posts Table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Posts] (
    [PostId]  INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]  INT             NOT NULL,
    [Content] NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [Date]    DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    [Picture] VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Posts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PostId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Posts_dbo.UserProfile_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserId]
    ON [dbo].[Posts]([UserId] ASC);
```

Comments Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Comments] (
    [CommentId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [PostId]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [Content]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Date]      DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Comments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CommentId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Comments_dbo.Posts_PostId] FOREIGN KEY ([PostId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Posts] ([PostId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PostId]
    ON [dbo].[Comments]([PostId] ASC);
```

Thank you

Comment: add where does PostId get set.   Is it null or default when teh savechanges is called ?   Is the field marked as identity on the DB ?

Comment: @soadyp Where I should add where does PostId get set ? I don't really know how to see if it's null or default. And yes my PostId field is marked as identity in my Post table, and as FK in my Comment table.

Comment: @soadyp so, my PostId is equal to 0 when the savechanges is called

Comment: Then the Model must have the correct navigational properties that reflect the foreign and both new objects in the context at once. Or the comment postid should be set to postid of the post it refers to. I would expect a Post/comment type of use case for these to always be independent commits. And therefore the postid on the comment should be set.

Comment: I see you have updated post to indicate the postid is set and nothing happens now.  "nothing happens" is hard to help, sorry.

Comment: Well, I know it's hard to help with this, but really nothing happens when I defined the HiddenFor field. Anyway, I've solved the issue and i've posted the solution in answer. Is that seems to be good practice to you ?

Answer (score 1):

you should set the PostId property on your Comment Model:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateComment(FormCollection values)
    {
        var comment = new Comment();
        TryUpdateModel(comment);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var context = new UsersContext();
            var username = User.Identity.Name;
            var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            var userid = user.UserId;

            comment.UserId = userid;
            comment.Date = DateTime.Now;
            //here
            comment.PostId = values["postId"];

            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Post");
        }
        ViewBag.PostId = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostId", "Content", comment.PostId);
        return View(comment);
    }
```

Comment: What mean `values["postId"]` ? Is it refered to an input field ? Like an hidden input for postId for example

Comment: It tells me that it cannot convert source type "string" to target type "int".

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I fix the issue by changing my CreateComment (httpPost) ActionResult with the following :

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateComment(FormCollection values, int id)
    {
        var comment = new Comment();
        TryUpdateModel(comment);

        /** ADD THIS LINE **/
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var context = new UsersContext();
            var username = User.Identity.Name;
            var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            var userid = user.UserId;

            comment.UserId = userid;
            comment.Date = DateTime.Now;

            /***  ADD THIS TWO LINES ***/
            comment.Post = post;
            comment.PostId = post.PostId;

            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Post");
        }            
        ViewBag.PostId = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostId", "Content", comment.PostId);
        return View(comment);
    }
```